# Why does the Broadcast receiver not work when restarted?

Tags: android, xml, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

This Broadcast does not work when the phone is restarted, other types of permissions have been used, but it still does not work. Has this problem occurred to you?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application ...


        <receiver
        android:name=".B_Boot"
        android:enabled="true">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

```
@SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    Alarm().setAlarm(context)
}
```

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: @xaif Thanks for your reply, but it still doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work", Please explain in more detail.